# Backward propagation slower as epochs increase in pytorch

Tags: neural-network, lstm, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm trying to replicate [TasNet paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.00541.pdf) using Pytorch Lightning, but the training time increases as the epochs increase (the first epoch takes 20 seconds, the fifth 2:30 minutes).
I've used PyTorch Lightning advanced profiler and it seems that the greater amount of time is spent in the backward propagation, so it seems like my computation graph is getting bigger, but I can't spot the issue.
Here is the code of the forward call of the model:

```py
    def forward(self, waveform: torch.Tensor) -> Any:
        mixture_weights, l2_norm = self.encoder(waveform)
        masks = self.separation_net(mixture_weights)
        sources = self.decoder(mixture_weights, masks, l2_norm)
        return sources

    def _common_step(self, batch: Any, batch_idx: int, stage: str) -> torch.Tensor:
        waveform, sources = batch
        sources_pred = self.forward(waveform)
        loss = self.loss_fn(sources_pred, sources)

        log_dict = {
            f"{stage}/{metric}": metric_fn(sources_pred, sources).detach()
            for metric, metric_fn in self.metrics_fn.items()
        }
        log_dict[f"{stage}/{self.loss}"] = loss.detach()
        self.log_dict(
            log_dict, on_epoch=True, on_step=False, prog_bar=False, logger=True
        )

        return loss
```

The slow part is the separation network which uses an LSTM:

```py
class LSTMStack(nn.Module):
    """A stacked LSTM module that consists of multiple LSTM blocks with residual connections.

    Args:
        input_size (int): The number of expected features in the input.
        hidden_size (int): The number of features in the hidden state of each LSTM block.
        layers_per_block (int): The number of recurrent layers within each LSTM block.
        num_blocks (int): The number of LSTM blocks to stack.
        bidirectional (bool): If True, the LSTM blocks are bidirectional; otherwise, they are unidirectional.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        input_size: int,
        hidden_size: int,
        layers_per_block: int,
        num_blocks: int,
        bidirectional: bool,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.layers_per_block = layers_per_block
        self.num_blocks = num_blocks
        self.bidirectional = bidirectional

        self.lstm_blocks = nn.ModuleList(
            [
                nn.LSTM(
                    input_size=self.input_size,
                    hidden_size=self.hidden_size,
                    num_layers=self.layers_per_block,
                    bidirectional=self.bidirectional,
                    batch_first=True,
                ),
            ]
            + [
                nn.LSTM(
                    input_size=self.hidden_size * 2
                    if self.bidirectional
                    else self.hidden_size,
                    hidden_size=self.hidden_size,
                    num_layers=self.layers_per_block,
                    bidirectional=self.bidirectional,
                    batch_first=True,
                )
                for _ in range(1, self.num_blocks)
            ]
        )

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        """Forward pass of the LSTMStack.

        Args:
            x (torch.Tensor): The input tensor of shape (batch size, num segments, basis length).

        Returns:
            torch.Tensor: The output tensor of the LSTMStack of shape (batch size, num segments, hidden size * 2)
                if the LSTM are bidirectional, otherwise (batch size, num segments, hidden size).
        """
        output, _ = self.lstm_blocks[0](x)

        if self.num_blocks > 1:
            for i in range(1, len(self.lstm_blocks)):
                residual = output
                output, _ = self.lstm_blocks[i](output)
                output = output + residual

        return output


class SeparationNetwork(nn.Module):
    """Separation module of TasNet.

    Args:
        basis_length (int): The length of basis signals.
        num_sources (int): The number of sources to separate.
        hidden_size (int): The size of hidden state in the LSTM layers.
        layers_per_block (int): The number of LSTM layers per block.
        num_blocks (int): The number of blocks in the LSTM stack.
        bidirectional (bool): Flag indicating whether the LSTM layers are bidirectional.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        basis_length: int,
        num_sources: int,
        hidden_size: int,
        layers_per_block: int,
        num_blocks: int,
        bidirectional: bool,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.basis_length = basis_length
        self.num_sources = num_sources
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.layers_per_block = layers_per_block
        self.num_blocks = num_blocks
        self.bidirectional = bidirectional

        self.instance_norm = nn.InstanceNorm1d(
            num_features=self.basis_length, affine=True
        )
        self.lstm_stack = LSTMStack(
            input_size=self.basis_length,
            hidden_size=self.hidden_size,
            layers_per_block=self.layers_per_block,
            num_blocks=self.num_blocks,
            bidirectional=self.bidirectional,
        )
        self.fully_connected = nn.Linear(
            in_features=self.hidden_size * 2
            if self.bidirectional
            else self.hidden_size,
            out_features=self.basis_length * self.num_sources,
        )

    def forward(self, mixture_weights: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        """Perform forward pass through the TasNetSeparationNetwork.

        Args:
            mixture_weights (torch.Tensor): Input mixture weights tensor of shape (batch_size, sequence_length, basis_length).

        Returns:
            torch.Tensor: Separated source masks tensor of shape (batch_size, num_sources, basis_length, sequence_length).
        """
        mixture_weights_normalized = self.instance_norm(mixture_weights)

        mixture_weights_normalized = einops.rearrange(
            mixture_weights_normalized, "b s k -> b k s"
        )
        hidden_masks = self.lstm_stack(mixture_weights_normalized)

        masks = torch.softmax(self.fully_connected(hidden_masks), dim=2)
        masks = einops.rearrange(
            masks, "b k (n s) -> b n k s", n=self.basis_length, s=self.num_sources
        )

        return masks
```

How can I make it faster?